# How to find duplicate values in nested data like this

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, find

I need a function to find duplicate colors in that kind of nested data

['black', 'white', 'red', 'black',[ 'black', 'purple', 'blue',[ 'purple', 'yellow', 'green', 'gray'], 'purple']]

expected result:

```
(2) ["Purple", "Yellow"]
```

Tried:

```
var color=['Blue', 'Red', 'Purple', 'Grey', 'Purple', 'Yellow', 'Yellow']

var uniq = color
.map((name) => {
  return {count: 1, name: name}
})
.reduce((a, b) => {
  a[b.name] = (a[b.name] || 0) + b.count
  return a
}, {})

var duplicates = Object.keys(uniq).filter((a) => uniq[a] > 1)

console.log(duplicates)
```

Comment: please add the wanted result and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) with [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and only add the item to the accumulated [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) if it doesn't appear at another index in the array.

```js
const colors = ['black', 'white', 'red', 'black',[ 'black', 'purple', 'blue',[ 'purple', 'yellow', 'green', 'gray'], 'purple']],

[...duplicates] = colors
                   .flat(2)
                   .reduce((acc, col, i, src) => 
                     src.lastIndexOf(col) !== i 
                     ? acc.add(col) : acc, 
                   new Set);

console.log(duplicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first project the array into a map of occurrences of a particular item, and then you can look at that list to determine the duplicate items (and the number of times it appears, if you want)

```
var arr = ['black', 'white', 'red', 'black', ['black', 'purple', 'blue', ['purple', 'yellow', 'green', 'gray'], 'purple']];

var occurrences = arr.flat(2).reduce(function(prev, cur) {
  prev[cur] = (prev[cur] || 0) + 1;
  return prev;
}, {});

var duplicates = Object.keys(occurrences).filter(key => occurrences[key] > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Program will check whether the value is array, if its array we will do recursion to handle inner array otherwise add value to [Set object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```
var colors = ['black', 'white', 'red', 'black', ['black', 'purple', 'blue', ['purple', 'yellow', 'green', 'gray'], 'purple']];

function uniqueFunc(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function (colorSet, value) {
        if (Array.isArray(value)) { uniqueFunc(value, colorSet); } else { colorSet.add(value) }
        return colorSet;
    }, arguments[1] ? arguments[1] : new Set());
}

console.log(Array.from(uniqueFunc(colors)));
```